# Teradata performances issues with left join big table

Tags: sql, query-optimization, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a sql performance issue when joining two tables on Teradata sql assistant, one of them ( table B) contain more than 3 billions rows so the join take more than 2 hours.

table A contain this columns

```
name|id_number|id_product|creation_date|cp_date|amount|rang
```

Table B Contain this columns

```
name|id_number|id_product_cp|creation_date|cp_date|amount|year_|month_
```

So i'm trying to get the amounts of each name/id_number/id_product

--> if the amount in table A = 0 then we get the amount of table B if it's not null
else we take the a amount.

My query is

```
select
    a.name,
    a.id_number,
    a.id_product,
    a.creation_date,
    case
        when
            sum(a.amount) = 0 and sum(net.amount) is not null then
                sum(net.amount)
            else
                sum(a.amount)
        end
    as amount
from 
    A a    
        left join (
            select
                a.name,
                a.id_number,
                a.cp_date(date) as cp_date,
                a.year_,
                a.month_,
                cp.id_product,
                sum(a.amount) as amount
            from
                B a 
                    join C cp
                    on cp.id_product_cp = a.id_product_cp
            group by 1,2,3,4,5,6
        ) net
        on
            a.name= net.name
            and a.id_number= net.id_number
            and a.id_product = net.id_product 
            and a.cp_date= net.cp_date
            and (
                        extract(year from a.cp_date) < net.year_
                    or (
                                extract(year from a.cp_date) = net.year_
                            and net.month_ >= extract(month from a.cp_date)
                        )
                ) 
    where a.rang <> 1
    group by 1,2,3,4
```

the below picture  is the results from the table dbc.QryLogStepsV for the query

[image]

I think that the subquery in the left join is the cause of the performance issue.

There is any way to perform this query please !

Thank you

Comment: At eye-ball I notice some syntax errors: (a) cp alias is not defined; (b) I could not find a function called 'cp_date'. Also, the 'select' clauses do not explicitly show from which table the columns come from...

Comment: Thank you @MarcusViniciusPompeu for the remark, i corrected the query

Comment: I' ve made another subtle edit in your query, highlighting how a.cp_date relates to net.year_ and net.month_. Although I did not understand the data, I think I can provide you a solution

Comment: Hard to tell without details. What's the Explain or even better data from dbc.QryLogStepsV for this query?

Comment: Hello @dnoeth i put the results from dbc.QryLogStepsV, i'm sorry i took a time to reply.

Comment: @dnoeth, i can see two steps  in the picture taking so long time the 3rd( the join) and even more the 6th ( the aggregation) ( for the exécution of today)

Comment: Thanks for the DBLQ-data, lots of info, but some columns,e.g. RowCount, are truncated. You already got *Incremental Planning & Execution* (StepName 'EPF'), this usually helps, but in your case it might just prevent an even worse plan, assuming steps <= 7 are the inner join/group. What's table `cp` and base table rowcounts?

Comment: thanks for your reply, i drop another picture more clear for the column truncated, the cp table is a referentiel table wich contain only 6K rows

Comment: Ok, the first join is many-many, more than doubling the number of rows to 5.8 bln. Is this logic correct?

Comment: if you mean the left join yes it is logic , but the inner join i don't think so

Comment: Well, step 2 is the CP table duplicated, which is then (probably product) joined in step 3 to B, returning 5.8 billion rows. Regardless if this is correct, you should try materializing this join in a MultiSet Volatile Table with a NUPI on all 6 join columns. It will take a while, but the following SUM step 6 should be much faster then. Btw, are there any additional WHERE-conditions in your query or does `a.rang <> 1` actually return no rows? (And this seems to be an Insert/Select)

Comment: Ok, i will test this the multiset volatile table without unique primary index also without the group by clause ( just select 6_columns from B join cp ) and do the group by in the left join. there is no other conditions in where clause and a.rang <> 1return always rows ( unless the table B is empty) , yes this query is under insert into table .

Comment: Materialize 7 columns (6 group + amount) in the VT, then left join to a Derived Table doing the aggregate). According to DBQL steps 1-9 are the net-Derived Table. And all other steps return RowCount 0.

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not provide a fiddle or a data sample, I will make my best guess, ok?

:-)

Is the query below faster and yet correct?

```
select
    a.name,
    a.id_number,
    a.id_product,
    a.creation_date,
    case
        when
            sum(a.amount) = 0 and sum(net.amount) is not null then
                sum(net.amount)
            else
                sum(a.amount)
        end
    as amount
from
    A a
        left join (
            select
                b.name,
                b.id_number,
                b.cp_date(date) as cp_date,
                --
                cast(
                    -- https://docs.teradata.com/r/kmuOwjp1zEYg98JsB8fu_A/7x~o21pczkQDFDjAA_5Olg
                    (b.year_ - 1900) * 10000 + b.month_ * 100 + 1 as date
                ) as cp_date_to_join,
                --
                cp.id_product,
                sum(b.amount) as amount
            from
                B b
                    join C cp
                    on cp.id_product_cp = b.id_product_cp
            group by
                1, 2, 3,
                4,
                5
        ) net
        on
                a.name       = net.name
            and a.id_number  = net.id_number
            and a.id_product = net.id_product
            and a.cp_date    = net.cp_date
            --
            and a.cp_date <= net.cp_date_to_join
    where a.rang <> 1
    group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: hello @Marcus Vinicius Pompeu, ( you missed + 01 as date ) i have  error for some number of data because of the conversion of column year_ and month_ to date, so it did not work correctly

Comment: I'm sorry, @mado. If you do not provide which errors you stumbled upon, for which data, I cannot help you...

Comment: By the way, @mado, thanks for the advice. I'm fixing the code for `+ 01 as date` :-)